# Get the enclosing class of a Java lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda

I have a method that takes a functional parameter, e.g. a `Runnable`. As it's a library method, I want it to use a logger derived from the functional parameter. Calling `getClass` on the functional parameter works fine for normal classes, and I can `getEnclosingClass` for nested or anonymous classes; but if it's a lambda expression, it returns some obscure name containing `$$Lambda$`, which I could strip off manually like this:

```
Class<?> type = runnable.getClass();
String canonical = type.getCanonicalName();
int lambdaOffset = canonical.indexOf("$$Lambda$");
if (lambdaOffset > 0) {
    try {
        type = Class.forName(canonical.substring(0, lambdaOffset));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // strange, but we can stick to the type we already have
    }
}
```

As you can see, that's not very elegant and probably not portable. I've tried `getEnclosingClass`, `getEnclosingMethod`, and `getEnclosingConstructor`, but they all return `null`.

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe this is by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a cool solution by [benjiweber](http://benjiweber.com/blog/2015/08/04/lambda-type-references/). It boils down to serializing the lamda to a `java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda` and then get its declaring class:

```
private static final int COUNT = 1_000_000;
private static boolean first = true;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
        showIdentity(() -> {
        });
    }
    String time = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format((double) (System.currentTimeMillis() - t) / COUNT);
    System.out.println("time per call: " + time + "ms");
}

public interface MethodAwareRunnable extends Runnable, Serializable {}

private static void showIdentity(MethodAwareRunnable consumer) {
    consumer.run();
    String name = name(consumer);
    if (first) {
        first = false;
        Class<?> clazz = consumer.getClass();
        System.out.printf("class name     : %s%n", clazz.getName());
        System.out.printf("class hashcode : %s%n", clazz.hashCode());
        System.out.printf("canonical name : %s%n", clazz.getCanonicalName());
        System.out.printf("enclosing class: %s%n", clazz.getEnclosingClass());
        System.out.printf("lambda name    : %s%n", name);
    }
}

private static String name(Object consumer) {
    return method(consumer).getDeclaringClass().getName();
}

private static SerializedLambda serialized(Object lambda) {
    try {
        Method writeMethod = lambda.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("writeReplace");
        writeMethod.setAccessible(true);
        return (SerializedLambda) writeMethod.invoke(lambda);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private static Class<?> getContainingClass(SerializedLambda lambda) {
    try {
        String className = lambda.getImplClass().replaceAll("/", ".");
        return Class.forName(className);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private static Method method(Object lambda) {
    SerializedLambda serialized = serialized(lambda);
    Class<?> containingClass = getContainingClass(serialized);
    return Arrays.stream(containingClass.getDeclaredMethods())
                 .filter(method -> Objects.equals(method.getName(), serialized.getImplMethodName()))
                 .findFirst()
                 .orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
}
```

This is a lot of code, but the overhead is about 0.003 ms on my machine, which is okay for most use cases.

And you can do other cool stuff like:

```
Map<String, String> hash = hash(
    hello -> "world",
    bob -> "was here"
);
```

Comment: Why do you do all this stuff only to the the enclosing `Class` of the lambda? Most probably your logger will do something similar `getLogger(clazz.getName())`. So why not using your initial approach and take the class name part till `$$Lambda*`?

Comment: @SubOptimal: You're right. This is what I already settled for; I just added this because it's so uber-cool ;-)

Comment: For me it would be usefull only in case the Lambda class name could not be derived in a simple way. But it follow this simple pattern `the.package.EnclosingClass$$Lambda$xx/yyyy`. Where `xx` is a sequential number per class and `yyy` is the hashcode of the Lambda. As always, the solution depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: The pattern for the class name is an implementation detail. The JDK can change that at any time. The approach above uses only official, documented APIs, so it's more stable. But you're right: This is mainly a theoretical discussion ;-)

Comment: I agree. Such kind of change would be discovered by a unit test. Which should be in place in such case. ;-) But your right this got more a theoretical dicsussion.

Answer (score 9):

As already mentioned by [Tassos Bassoukos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/397786/tassos-bassoukos) it is by design.

The bytecode for the Lambda (class) is generated at runtime. So what you get is the actual name of the class. And the name is generated as `target class name + "$$Lambda$" + a counter`.

Find a small snippet for demonstration.

```
package sub.optimal;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class EnclosingClass {

    static class InnerRunnable implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            out.println("--- inner class");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        showIdentity(() -> System.out.println("--- lambda 1"));
        showIdentity(() -> System.out.println("--- lambda 2"));
        showIdentity(new InnerRunnable());
        showIdentity(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                out.println("--- anonymous class");
            }
        });
    }

    private static void showIdentity(Runnable runnable) {
        runnable.run();
        Class<? extends Runnable> clazz = runnable.getClass();
        out.printf("class name     : %s%n", clazz.getName());
        out.printf("class hashcode : %s%n", clazz.hashCode());
        out.printf("canonical name : %s%n", clazz.getCanonicalName());
        out.printf("enclosing class: %s%n", clazz.getEnclosingClass());
        out.println();
    }
}
```

**output**

```
--- lambda 1
class name     : sub.optimal.EnclosingClass$$Lambda$1/2147972
class hashcode : 2147972
canonical name : sub.optimal.EnclosingClass$$Lambda$1/2147972
enclosing class: null

--- lambda 2
class name     : sub.optimal.EnclosingClass$$Lambda$2/10376386
class hashcode : 10376386
canonical name : sub.optimal.EnclosingClass$$Lambda$2/10376386
enclosing class: null

--- inner class
class name     : sub.optimal.EnclosingClass$InnerRunnable
class hashcode : 28014437
canonical name : sub.optimal.EnclosingClass.InnerRunnable
enclosing class: class sub.optimal.EnclosingClass

--- anonymous class
class name     : sub.optimal.EnclosingClass$1
class hashcode : 19451386
canonical name : null
enclosing class: class sub.optimal.EnclosingClass
```

Comment: This is correct for jdk 1.8, the behaviour has changed in jdk 11.

Comment: The name pattern can change with every release; it's not specified anywhere.

Comment: @rü I agree. We discussed that point in 2017. ;-) In any case build code which depends on implementation internals should be avoided. If there is a real need to depend on, that case needs to be covered by a unit test, with the aim to fail when the behavior changed.